# Python orm datetime issue

Tags: python, mysql-python, peewee

I have a Peewee database model Products in a very big database with a datetime field.
when i want to select articles with (inserted time bigger than now()) the query hangs forever.

```
class Products(BaseModel):
    id = IntegerField()
    name= CharField()
    inserted = DateTimeField()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'products'

Products.select().where(Products.inserted >datetime(2013, 04, 03, 14, 52, 50).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

I'm not sure if it's because of the database size (bigger than 10 GB) or it's because of the query style.

Should i use datetime like this datetime(2013, 04, 03, 14, 52, 50) or "2013-04-03 14:52:50" ?

Comment: There should be *no* need to format the `datetime` object to a string. SQLAlchemy knows how to handle `datetime` objects itself just fine.

Comment: If the query takes forever, then that is usually a problem with the database structure. Is there an index covering the `inserted` column?

Comment: You should not need to format the datetime -- peewee will handle python datetime objects.  I'm guessing you may need to add an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peewee will accept `datetime` objects as input, so you do not need to do any conversion.  I would guess the problem is you are missing an index.

Try:

```
class Products(BaseModel):
    id = IntegerField(primary_key=True) # <-- You should specify a Primary Key
    name= CharField()
    inserted = DateTimeField(index=True) # <-- this should be an index

Products.select().where(Products.inserted >datetime(2013, 04, 03, 14, 52, 50))
```

If your table already exists, you can add an index programmatically using the python shell:

```
# assuming your db is named "db"
db.create_index(Products, [Products.inserted])
```

Comment: Thats exactly the case , Peewee wasn't considering the column as an index , hence the time it took to gather data.
Thanks!